# Как динамически изменить content на button?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, wpf-canvas

У меня есть приложение, как показано на рисунке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Button выступает в роли ползунка по канвасу. По задумке должно быть так: При перемещении кнопки на ней должна отображаться дата. 
Я пытался это реализовать следующий образом:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas canvas = FindVisualChildByName<Canvas>(Tablica, "cnvs");
        int number = 0;

        Control control = sender as Control;    
        Point x = e.GetPosition(canvas);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {

            Canvas.SetLeft(control, Canvas.GetLeft(control) + (x.X - p.X));
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(365 * Convert.ToDouble(x.X) / Tablica.Columns[4].ActualWidth);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(365 * (Convert.ToDouble(x.X)) / Tablica.Columns[4].ActualWidth + control.ActualWidth / 3);
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01);
            date = date.AddDays(a);
            DateTime dateOne = new DateTime(2021, 01, 01);
            dateOne = dateOne.AddDays(b);
            string s = date.ToString("dd/MM")/* + " - " + dateOne.ToString("dd/MM")*/;
            db.OpenConn();
            DataTable dt = db.ReadVol("SELECT Personal.[Subname], Personal.[FirstName], Personal.[Patronomyc] FROM Personal;");
            db.CloseCon();
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
                if (dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == Label) {
                    number = i;
                }
            }
            collection[number].Time = s;

        }
        p = x;
    }
```

Но, дата не отображается как контент у кнопки. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: А где тут кнопка? Игра с канвасом, датами, даже с БД играетесь, а где же пресловутая кнопка?

Comment: @Bulson В первой строке таблицы. Как раз весь код в Button_PreviewMouseMove

Comment: В вопросе куча ненужной инфы. Читайте, как [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: А почему не взять готовый Slyder?

Comment: @Bulson `sender` же

Answer (score 1):

```csharp
Control control = sender as Control;
```

поменяйте на

```csharp
Button button = sender as Button;
```

затем

```csharp
button.Content = s;
```

Comment: А почему вы уверены, что `sender` - это кнопка, если сам автор кода в этом не уверен ?

Comment: @Bulson я ни в чем не уверен, но подозреваю, что он не стал бы умышленно переименовывать обработчик события, чтобы всех нас обмануть. :)

Comment: Только на это и стоит уповать...

Comment: @Anton69 ответил ли я на ваш вопрос?